# What is the shelf life of vegetable seeds?

Tags: vegetables, seeds

I bought a packet of vegetable seeds from Costco a few years back.  I still have seeds left in individual packages.  Is there a life to these seeds after which it is not recommended for use?  What is the impact of using seeds after the shelf life of the seeds?  Is it just lower germination rate or could this impact the quality of the vegetables/plants produced from old seeds?

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the type of vegetables that you have. Check the seed packet. There should be an expiration date at the back. As long as the seeds have been kept dry, they should be fine. If not, the germination rate will be lower

Comment: A quick search for ( "plant name" seed viability ) usually returns good results.